# Create Arrays <Objects> From xml file

Tags: java, arrays, xml

everyone!

I’m facing the problem of getting data to create an object from the following XML file.

```
<staff>
<employee>
    <id>1</id>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <country>USA</country>
    <age>25</age>
</employee>
<employee>
    <id>2</id>
    <firstName>Inav</firstName>
    <lastName>Petrov</lastName>
    <country>RU</country>
    <age>23</age>
</employee>
```

I can't get the value of the attribute through the method getAttributeValue().

all I got was to get the value in the format String with method getTextContent.

```
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.parse("data.xml"); 
Node root = document.getDocumentElement(); 
NodeList staff = root.getChildNodes(); 
for (int i = 0; i < staff.getLength(); i++) {
Node employee = staff.item(i);

if (employee.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    NodeList employeeProps = employee.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < employeeProps.getLength(); j++) {
        Node employeeProp = employeeProps.item(j);

        if (employeeProp.getNodeType() != Node.TEXT_NODE)
            employeeProp.getTextContent();
            // **TODO Employee?**

    }

}
```

tell me please how you can implement this idea, and still get the value to create an object of the class Employee?

Comment: There is no attribute in this XML! ?

Comment: "all I got was to get the value in the format String with method getTextContent." - All you have in your XML are strings, so what are you expecting to get? Also, do you have to implement that yourself our would it be possible to use a library like [JAXB](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/) or Jackson with a [XML plugin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml)? Another option might be to use [XPath](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xpath).

Comment: there really is no attribute, using the tool DOM is it possible to create the required object from strings?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use XPath for this kind of things:

```
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList staff = root.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < staff.getLength(); i++) {
            Node employee = staff.item(i);
            System.out.println(eval(employee, "id"));
            System.out.println(eval(employee, "firstName")
                    + " " + eval(employee, "lastName"));
        }


public static String eval(Node node, String expr)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    return (String)eval(node, expr, XPathConstants.STRING);
}

public static Node evalNode(Node node, String expr)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    return (Node)eval(node, expr, XPathConstants.NODE);
}

private static Object eval(Node node, String expr, QName type)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    return xpath.evaluate(expr, node, type);
}
```

UPDATE: Or rather:

```
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList staff = evalNodes(root, "employee");
        for (int i = 0; i < staff.getLength(); i++) {
            Node employee = staff.item(i);
            String id = eval(employee, "id");
            System.out.println(id);
            System.out.println(eval(employee, "firstName")
                    + " " + eval(employee, "lastName"));
        }

public static String eval(Node node, String expr)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    return (String)eval(node, expr, XPathConstants.STRING);
}

public static Node evalNode(Node node, String expr)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    return (Node)eval(node, expr, XPathConstants.NODE);
}

public static NodeList evalNodes(Node node, String expr)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    return (NodeList)eval(node, expr, XPathConstants.NODESET);
}

private static Object eval(Node node, String expr, QName type)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    return xpath.evaluate(expr, node, type);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but implementation is required using the tool DOM

Comment: @ViktorLoskutov it does

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend having a look at [Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html) and [How XPath Works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html) probably wouldn't hurt

It's been a REALLY long time since I had to do any XML or xPath related work, so there may be some enhancements that could be applied, but the basic idea might look something like...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse("data.xml"));

        String expression = "/staff/employee";
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Object result = xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(25);

        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        for (int index = 0; index < nodes.getLength(); index++) {
            Node node = nodes.item(index);
            Employee employee = employeeFrom(node);
            employees.add(employee);
        }

        System.out.println(employees.size());

        for (Employee emp : employees) {
            System.out.println("[" + emp.getId() + "] " + emp.getFirstName() + " " + emp.getLastName() + "; " + emp.getCountry() + "; " + emp.getAge());
        }
    }

    protected Employee employeeFrom(Node node) throws XPathExpressionException {
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        int id = ((Double)xPath.compile("id/text()").evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NUMBER)).intValue();
        String firstName = (String)xPath.compile("firstName/text()").evaluate(node, XPathConstants.STRING);
        String lastName = (String)xPath.compile("lastName/text()").evaluate(node, XPathConstants.STRING);
        String country = (String)xPath.compile("country/text()").evaluate(node, XPathConstants.STRING);
        int age = ((Double)xPath.compile("age/text()").evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NUMBER)).intValue();

        return new Employee(id, firstName, lastName, country, age);
    }

    public class Employee {
        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String country;
        private int age;

        public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String country, int age) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.country = country;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }


    }

}
```

Now, the code is making some assumptions about the structure and isn't doing any kind of error handling, so you might need to look into that as well.

> Need use only methods class DOM, without xPath
> this is a requirement of technical documentation

None of this was specified in the question, if you have "limitations" on what you can do, then you need to make sure that they are mentioned within the question, otherwise you'll get people doing it the "best" ways possible.

With the above "restrictions", I'm honestly not sure why you're asking the question, as it could easily be researched through a simple google search

- [How to read XML file in Java – (DOM Parser)](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)
- [Java DOM Parser - Parse XML Document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm)
- [XML Parsing for Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK3000)

would be some starting points.

I went a slightly different route, but it will give the same results in the end...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public final class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/stackoverflow/data.xml"));

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(25);

        Node root = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList staff = root.getChildNodes();
        for (int index = 0; index < staff.getLength(); index++) {
            Node node = staff.item(index);
            if ("employee".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                Employee employee = parseEmployeeNode(node);
                if (employee != null) {
                    employees.add(employee);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(employees.size());

        for (Employee emp : employees) {
            System.out.println("[" + emp.getId() + "] " + emp.getFirstName() + " " + emp.getLastName() + "; " + emp.getCountry() + "; " + emp.getAge());
        }
    }

    protected Employee parseEmployeeNode(Node node) {
        NodeList properties = node.getChildNodes();
        EmployeeBuilder builder = new EmployeeBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < properties.getLength(); index++) {
            Node propertyNode = properties.item(index);
            if ("id".equals(propertyNode.getNodeName())) {
                builder.setId(intValueFromNodeTextContent(propertyNode));
            } else if ("firstName".equals(propertyNode.getNodeName())) {
                builder.setFirstName(propertyNode.getTextContent());
            } else if ("lastName".equals(propertyNode.getNodeName())) {
                builder.setLastName(propertyNode.getTextContent());
            } else if ("country".equals(propertyNode.getNodeName())) {
                builder.setCountry(propertyNode.getTextContent());
            } else if ("age".equals(propertyNode.getNodeName())) {
                builder.setAge(intValueFromNodeTextContent(propertyNode));
            }
        }
        Employee employee = null;
        try {
            employee = builder.build();
        } catch (EmployeeBuilder.MissingParameterException ex) {
            System.out.println("Warning: failed to parse employee: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return employee;
    }

    protected Integer intValueFromNodeTextContent(Node node) {
        String value = node.getTextContent();
        Integer intValue = null;
        try {
            intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("Warning: could not convert " + value + " to int value");
        }
        return intValue;
    }

    public class EmployeeBuilder {

        private Integer id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String country;
        private Integer age;

        public Employee build() throws MissingParameterException {
            if (id == null) {
                throw new MissingParameterException("id");
            }
            if (firstName == null) {
                throw new MissingParameterException("firstName");
            }
            if (lastName == null) {
                throw new MissingParameterException("lastName");
            }
            if (country == null) {
                throw new MissingParameterException("country");
            }
            if (age == null) {
                throw new MissingParameterException("age");
            }

            return new Employee(id, firstName, lastName, country, age);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public EmployeeBuilder setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public EmployeeBuilder setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            return this;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public EmployeeBuilder setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
            return this;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public EmployeeBuilder setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
            return this;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public EmployeeBuilder setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public class MissingParameterException extends Exception {

            public MissingParameterException(String parameterName) {
                super("Missing parameter " + parameterName);
            }

        }
    }

    public class Employee {

        private int id;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String country;
        private int age;

        public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String country, int age) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.country = country;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not going to try and explain the code or justify it's design, you're going to have to analysis this yourself, but if I was your instructor/lead, I'd have questions over why you'd made certain decisions ;)

Comment: Need use only methods class DOM, without xPath

Comment: Well, don't you just hate yourself then :P

Comment: this is a requirement of technical documentation